# Simple Mail List adding blank table row in SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple mail list that I had working when it was just an e-mail address, but I have decided to add a name column, and cant figure out what's going wrong.

When a user submits the form, the email address is added in the email column, but in the name column it just blank. Also, it is adding a new blank table row every time.

Here is the code for the form....

```
<form id="addressForm" action="index.php" method="get">
    <p>
      <input class="formname" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Your Name" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='Your Name'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Your Name':this.value;">
      <input class="formemail" type="text" name="address" id="address" value="Your E-mail" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='Your E-mail'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Your E-mail':this.value;">
      <input class="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    </p>
    <p id="response"><?php echo(storeAddress()); ?></p>
</form>
```

And here is the php...

```
    <?
require_once("dbConstants.php");

function storeAddress() {
  $message = "&nbsp;";
  // Check for an email address in the query string
  if( !isset($_GET['address']) ){
    // No email address provided
  }
  else {
    // Get details from the query string
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $address = $_GET['address'];
    // Validate Address
    if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i", $address)) {
      $message = "<strong>Error</strong>: An invalid email address was provided.";
    }
    else {
      // Connect to database
      $con = mysql_connect(DBHOST ,DBUSER, DBPASS);
      mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $con);
      // Insert email address into mailinglist table 
      $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mailinglist SET name='" . $name . "'");
      $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mailinglist SET email='" . $address . "'");
      if(mysql_error()){
        $message = "<strong>Error</strong>: There was an error storing your email address.";
      }
      else {
        $message = "Thanks for signing up!";
      }
    }
  }
  return $message;
}
?>
```

When adding the new row into phpmyadmin, i used the SQL query

```
ALTER TABLE mailinglist ADD column_name name;
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong with the code that would create the extra row?

Comment: Check your `SQL` syntax, you `INSERT` - `VALUES`. You don't `INSERT` - `SET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inserting two rows into your database. First one with name and second one with e-mail address. You should insert those values in one query like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mailinglist(name, email) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $address . "')");
```

You should also check if there is something in `$_GET['name']` because your question indicates that it is empty (empty row inserted).

As a sidenote, I'd like to add that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated in PHP. You should switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Yes that fixed the blank row problem, but it still isnt putting a value into the name column. Does this mean I should be checking the value for name where I have if( !isset($_GET['address'])?

Comment: Probably the input name in your HTML form is not `'name'`. Make a `var_dump($_GET)` at the begining of your function and see what actually comes from user.

Comment: Yeah I checked that, but the form is like this '<input class="formname" type="text" name="name" id="name">'

Comment: Update your question and post your whole `<form>` code there.

Comment: Your HTML looks OK, but `ALTER TABLE` you posted seems not quite valid. Are you sure there is a column named `name` in your DB?

Comment: yeah I have, with the following settings, Field:name, Type:text, Collation:latin1_general_ci, Null:no. If it helps, you can see the page live at balisurfmap.webfroth.co.uk

Comment: You have a javascript function on your site wich sends your values to a script named ajaxServer.php. And in this function you add value only from address field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39918/discussion-between-chris-collins-and-jojo)